# Multiple subfigures not appearing on the same line

Tags: captions, plot, subcaption

Multiple figures under a single caption. I have tried a code to put two images in a together under a same caption. The `subfigure`s do not appear on the same line.

The code is :

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
        \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
    \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/study.jpeg}
                                    \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
                    \caption{the distribution of the nodes in the study site}
                    \label{fig:sensor3}
            \end{subfigure}%    <-- % added here
            \hfill %% useful if width of each figure is less the .5\textwidth
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/coord.jpeg}
                                    \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
                    \caption{the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system}
                    \label{fig:tiger}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment} \label{fig:Sensor}
                    \FloatBarrier
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Problem occurred with the code:

[image]

Comment: What is the error you're receiving that makes it "not work properly?"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) When I put your code into a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  it works fine for me...

Comment: Not, error but plot doesn't appear in a same line. And figures are presented separately in different rows.

Comment: Maybe `\rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}`?

Comment: Please, make the code into a complete compilable example.

Comment: It seems you asked the same question again instead of giving more details in the old question. Please give more details on previous question regarding why the solution provided there is not not helpful.

Comment: Why did you repeat the same question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89381/subfigures-not-appearing-on-a-same-line

Answer (score 11):

You need to put a `%` after the first subfigure since the width of each subfigure is `.5\textwidth`. Also you may need a `\hfill` if the width is less than `.5\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/study.jpeg}
                \caption{the distribution of the nodes in the study site}
                \label{fig:sensor3}
        \end{subfigure}%    <-- % added here
        \hfill %% useful if width of each figure is less the .5\textwidth
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/study_road.jpeg}
                \caption{the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system}
                \label{fig:tiger}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment} \label{fig:Sensor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But using a width of little less than `.5\textwidth` (say `.49\textwidth`) makes it look better IMO.

[image]

## Edit

Your problem (now) is the `\rule{35em}{0.3pt}` for which you have put a length of `35em`. Actually subfigures are put in a `minipage` of of specified width. Hence this results in a `badbox` warning. Use `\rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}` (or `\linewidth`) and `badbox`es run away.

Also, you are using `\FloatBarrier` inside the `figure` environment, which shouldn't be done. Move it outside as in my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption,placeins,blindtext}

\begin{document}
        \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
    \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/study.jpeg}
                                    \rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}
                    \caption{the distribution of the nodes in the study site}
                    \label{fig:sensor3}
            \end{subfigure}%    <-- % added here
            \hfill %% useful if width of each figure is less the .5\textwidth
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/coord.jpeg}
                                    \rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}
                    \caption{the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system}
                    \label{fig:tiger}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment} \label{fig:Sensor}
    \end{figure}
    \FloatBarrier %% put this here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\centering` commands inside the `subfigure` environments aren't needed because the graph objects take up the full widths of these environments.

Comment: The code still doesn't work properly. I have edited the question and problem illustrated there.

Comment: @Topdombili Which code? What are the details of doesn't work? Did you put the `%` as I told?

Comment: @HarishKumar, Yes, I have added % as you mentioned. The latest code is updated in question.

Comment: @HarishKumar, I updated the question late. Sorry for that. I tries %.

Comment: @HarishKumar, Unfortunately, No. The plot presented as I put in question. Could it be cause because of initial size of the images?

Comment: @Topdombili It should work irrespective of initial size of plots? With the details you are giving it is hard to say. Just put the figures in my MWE (don't use your code) and let me know. Ah... Remove `demo` option from `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Comment: I tried without demo, a same problem still exist. I put images in https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pfo01z69hotr70d/P8T3Fj7GRW

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems seems to be that you give your `\rule` commands a fixed width and therefore the subfigures are wider than the stated half `\linewidth`. I reset the rules to the length of `\linewidth` which is the width of your subfigures. Above that I put some `%` sign at the end of the first `subfigure` environment (Important: there must be *no* whitespace between the last character and the `%` sign) to eliminate the space between the two subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \rule{\linewidth}{10em}
            \rule{\linewidth}{0.3pt}
                    \caption{the distribution of the nodes in the study site}
                    \label{fig:sensor3}
            \end{subfigure}%
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \rule{\linewidth}{6em}
               \rule{\linewidth}{0.3pt}
                    \caption{the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system}
                    \label{fig:tiger}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment} \label{fig:Sensor}   
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following output (I replaced the images by simple `\rule` commands:

[image]

For the subcaptions appearing in the List of Figures: this is a feature of the `subcaptions` package, not a bug. As far as I could see from the package documentation there is no simple option to turn this off.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed `\FloatBarrier` and got:

[image]

which is what I think you wanted.

Comment: There's still the problem of the too long rule, but `\FloatBarrier` definitely goes *outside* the `figure` environment.

Answer (score 1):

I never used `subcaption` package, but it seems to me that `subfigure` package can be useful for you.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage{subfigure}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}

    \subfigure [the distribution of the nodes in the study site] {
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig2.jpg}
        %\caption{the distribution of the nodes in the study site}
        \label{fig:sensor3}
    }
    \subfigure[The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1.jpg}
         \label{fig:tiger}
    }
    \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment}
    \label{fig:Sensor}   

    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned the ``subfigure`` package hasn't seen any development for some time now and the ``subcaption`` package is the most actively developed package for this purpose.