# Subfigures not appearing on a same line

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, subfloats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple subfigures not appearing on the same line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89183/multiple-subfigures-not-appearing-on-the-same-line)

I have tried this code to put two images with together under a same caption. The subfigures do not appear on the same line. Moreover, even in the table of content they are presented as different tables, separately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
    \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
    \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figur/study.jpeg}
            \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
                    \caption{the distribution of the nodes in the study site}
                    \label{fig:sensor3}
            \end{subfigure}%    
            \hfill 
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/coord.jpeg}
               \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
                    \caption{the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system}
                    \label{fig:tiger}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment} \label{fig:Sensor}   
    \FloatBarrier
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Problem happened in plotting:

[image]